# ruby on rails date format problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi
In my application the user can selects a date in a  "dd/mm/yyyy" format from a calendar and save it to a date field in the database (mySql).
Everything is going ok on my local server (in Israel) but on my host server ( in the US) it fails.
I did some checking in the console and found that 
**in my local computer(Israel)** when I do the following:

> d=Date.new
>   d.reported_date="23/01/2011",br>
>   d.save
>   I get
>   =>true.

**In my host server(US)** when I do the following:

> d=Date.new
>   d.reported_date="23/01/2011"
>   d.save
>   I get
>   =>false

When I did this check with another date for example "04/01/2011"
the local and the host could save the record.

So I concluded  that it seems like  the host(in US)  can receive date only  in "mm/dd/yyyy" format and convert it to mySql date format
and the local computer(in Israel) can received date only in "dd/mm/yyyy" format and convert it to mySql   date format.
(Both in the server and in my local machine the format in the mySql server is  yyyy-mm-dd)

I need to find a solution which can  adjust  mySql in my local machine to behave like in the host server.

I will be glad to some advise

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using yyyy-mm-dd instead, that can never be read wrong and all databases I have worked with accepts that format.

Comment: I check it and it is working both the server host and my local computer can accept dates in format yyyy-mm-dd
But I wonder if there is a way to do it in some setting file so I didn't have to do this conversion in the application

Comment: Sorry, have never worked with ruby, but I have used a lot of databases ;)

Answer (score 1):

try to use `puts DateTime.strptime(inputStr, "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")`